# Reference Point for Potential Energy

Tags: energy, reference-frames, energy-conservation, potential-energy, conventions

The title is quite misleading, sorry for that i couldn't think of any other title.

Energy is a certain quantity whose value is constant anywhere in space. There are different forms of energy such as kinetic and potential energy which interchange in the prescence of a gravitational field.

Suppose a ball from infinity is brought on earth and kept on a tall building. What potential energy would it have? Would it be the same if a ball from ground is kept on a that same tall building?

I am asking this beacause it is given in my book that "the choice of reference point is your own".

Comment: I think the take-away is that the only things that are meaningful in a calculation are   energy *differences* not the value itself of the energy.  We often pave over that point in introductory presentation.   That's unfortunate because it sometimes leads to confusion such as yours.

Comment: @garyp if we take the potential energy of one of the subtrahend as zero then we can find potential energy at that point.

Comment: @TheoreticalNcert Gravitational potential energy is a property of a system which contains at least two masses.  There is no such thing as the potential energy of a mass.

Comment: @Farcher then why do we need a reference point, and why should it be zero

Comment: @TheoreticalNcert Your reference point doesn't have to be zero. It can be anything you want it to be *as long as you're consistent with it.* See also answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the text says calculate the potential energy, it means that calculate the potential energy difference from the choice of you reference point. Taking the following example where I choose $y_0$ to be my reference point.
 $$\int_{U(y_0)}^{U(y)}dU=\int_{y_0}^{y}mgdy$$
$$U(y)-U(y_0)=mg(y-y_0)$$
Now, if I choose $U(y_0)$ to be $0$, its the matter of convenience, that now $U(y)$ is my potential difference w.r.t to my reference point. So you can absolutely take your reference as infinity and take the ball from infinity to the roof of the building, but be aware that the potential energy difference is now w.r.t to infinity. The answer of you "potential energy" varies depends on your reference point.

Comment: Thanks, i kind of get it now. So It means Difference in Potential Energy depends on Frame of Reference as it will be different wrt to earth and different wrt to infinity.

Comment: Exactly, so you have to be careful from the choice of your reference. Sometimes the choice of your reference point makes the whole calculation extremely cumbersome.

Comment: this question and your answer really confused me. In real life(Volts) which reference do we use?

Comment: If you are talking about volts in electricity, then in a cell potential is measured between anode and cathode. The electricity that comes in the houses are between line and neutral (sometimes ground).